How to verify in JSON reponse for post xode "70597" the place name has "Stuttgart Degerloch" exists?
I am a learner in Postman and trying to learn how to read a JSON File in Postman. My question is, how can I make a test using script to ensure that for the post code "70597", there exists a place name called "Stuttgart Degerloch"?
My JSON looks like this:
{
    "country abbreviation": "DE",
    "places": [
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1767",
            "post code": "70173",
            "latitude": "48.7786"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70173",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70174",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.172",
            "post code": "70174",
            "latitude": "48.7827"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Nord",
            "longitude": "9.1921",
            "post code": "70174",
            "latitude": "48.7978"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70176",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1585",
            "post code": "70176",
            "latitude": "48.7752"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-West",
            "longitude": "9.1641",
            "post code": "70176",
            "latitude": "48.7736"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-West",
            "longitude": "9.1641",
            "post code": "70178",
            "latitude": "48.7736"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1731",
            "post code": "70178",
            "latitude": "48.7728"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70178",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Süd",
            "longitude": "9.1678",
            "post code": "70178",
            "latitude": "48.7644"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70180",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1762",
            "post code": "70180",
            "latitude": "48.7649"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Süd",
            "longitude": "9.1678",
            "post code": "70180",
            "latitude": "48.7644"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70182",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1821",
            "post code": "70182",
            "latitude": "48.7745"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70184",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Frauenkopf",
            "longitude": "9.2218",
            "post code": "70184",
            "latitude": "48.7607"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Süd",
            "longitude": "9.1678",
            "post code": "70184",
            "latitude": "48.7644"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Ost",
            "longitude": "9.2079",
            "post code": "70184",
            "latitude": "48.7819"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.1798",
            "post code": "70184",
            "latitude": "48.7759"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70186",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Ost",
            "longitude": "9.2042",
            "post code": "70186",
            "latitude": "48.7718"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70188",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.2112",
            "post code": "70188",
            "latitude": "48.7836"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Ost",
            "longitude": "9.2079",
            "post code": "70188",
            "latitude": "48.7819"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Ost",
            "longitude": "9.2079",
            "post code": "70190",
            "latitude": "48.7819"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70190",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
            "longitude": "9.2019",
            "post code": "70190",
            "latitude": "48.7887"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70191",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Bad Cannstatt",
            "longitude": "9.2141",
            "post code": "70191",
            "latitude": "48.8056"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Nord",
            "longitude": "9.1824",
            "post code": "70191",
            "latitude": "48.7974"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Feuerbach",
            "longitude": "9.1588",
            "post code": "70192",
            "latitude": "48.8113"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70192",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Nord",
            "longitude": "9.1921",
            "post code": "70192",
            "latitude": "48.7978"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70193",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-West",
            "longitude": "9.1641",
            "post code": "70193",
            "latitude": "48.7736"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Nord",
            "longitude": "9.1557",
            "post code": "70193",
            "latitude": "48.7784"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70195",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Botnang",
            "longitude": "9.1304",
            "post code": "70195",
            "latitude": "48.7762"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70197",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-West",
            "longitude": "9.1485",
            "post code": "70197",
            "latitude": "48.767"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Süd",
            "longitude": "9.1678",
            "post code": "70199",
            "latitude": "48.7644"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-West",
            "longitude": "9.1509",
            "post code": "70199",
            "latitude": "48.7582"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70199",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Rotenberg",
            "longitude": "9.2715",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7833"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Hedelfingen",
            "longitude": "9.2557",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7586"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Luginsland",
            "longitude": "9.2579",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7931"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Wangen",
            "longitude": "9.2478",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7687"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Ost",
            "longitude": "9.2444",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7726"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Untertürkheim",
            "longitude": "9.2509",
            "post code": "70327",
            "latitude": "48.7802"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70329",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Uhlbach",
            "longitude": "9.2788",
            "post code": "70329",
            "latitude": "48.7762"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Rohracker",
            "longitude": "9.2618",
            "post code": "70329",
            "latitude": "48.7618"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Obertürkheim",
            "longitude": "9.2683",
            "post code": "70329",
            "latitude": "48.7646"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.2177",
            "post code": "70372",
            "latitude": "48.8026"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Bad Cannstatt",
            "longitude": "9.2141",
            "post code": "70372",
            "latitude": "48.8056"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70374",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Bad Cannstatt",
            "longitude": "9.2141",
            "post code": "70374",
            "latitude": "48.8056"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Sommerrain",
            "longitude": "9.2367",
            "post code": "70374",
            "latitude": "48.8106"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Burgholzhof",
            "longitude": "9.2124",
            "post code": "70376",
            "latitude": "48.8137"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Münster",
            "longitude": "9.22",
            "post code": "70376",
            "latitude": "48.8213"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Bad Cannstatt",
            "longitude": "9.2141",
            "post code": "70376",
            "latitude": "48.8056"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70376",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.227",
            "post code": "70378",
            "latitude": "48.837"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70435",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zuffenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1656",
            "post code": "70435",
            "latitude": "48.8334"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zuffenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1938",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.8353"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Rot",
            "longitude": "9.1927",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.8341"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Mönchfeld",
            "longitude": "9.2192",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.8424"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zazenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1928",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.8409"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Freiberg",
            "longitude": "9.2049",
            "post code": "70437",
            "latitude": "48.8363"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Neuwirtshaus",
            "longitude": "9.1424",
            "post code": "70439",
            "latitude": "48.8357"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zuffenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1525",
            "post code": "70439",
            "latitude": "48.8412"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70439",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Stammheim",
            "longitude": "9.156",
            "post code": "70439",
            "latitude": "48.8493"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Feuerbach",
            "longitude": "9.1612",
            "post code": "70469",
            "latitude": "48.8098"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70469",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zuffenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1675",
            "post code": "70469",
            "latitude": "48.8141"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Giebel",
            "longitude": "9.0891",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8067"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Weilimdorf",
            "longitude": "9.1123",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8143"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Hausen",
            "longitude": "9.0829",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8151"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Wolfbusch",
            "longitude": "9.1118",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8125"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Bergheim",
            "longitude": "9.0897",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8013"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Zuffenhausen",
            "longitude": "9.1685",
            "post code": "70499",
            "latitude": "48.8323"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Möhringen",
            "longitude": "9.1464",
            "post code": "70563",
            "latitude": "48.7258"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70563",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Vaihingen",
            "longitude": "9.103",
            "post code": "70563",
            "latitude": "48.7294"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Dürrlewang",
            "longitude": "9.1181",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7195"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Fasanenhof",
            "longitude": "9.1509",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7124"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Möhringen",
            "longitude": "9.1464",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7258"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Vaihingen",
            "longitude": "9.1247",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7248"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Rohr",
            "longitude": "9.106",
            "post code": "70565",
            "latitude": "48.7172"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Möhringen",
            "longitude": "9.1464",
            "post code": "70567",
            "latitude": "48.7258"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70567",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Degerloch",
            "longitude": "9.1534",
            "post code": "70567",
            "latitude": "48.7237"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Vaihingen",
            "longitude": "9.1097",
            "post code": "70569",
            "latitude": "48.7301"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Kaltental",
            "longitude": "9.1293",
            "post code": "70569",
            "latitude": "48.7383"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70569",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Büsnau",
            "longitude": "9.0798",
            "post code": "70569",
            "latitude": "48.7506"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Degerloch",
            "longitude": "9.1703",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7496"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Kaltental",
            "longitude": "9.1293",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7383"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Hoffeld",
            "longitude": "9.1739",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7425"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Möhringen",
            "longitude": "9.1464",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7258"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Sonnenberg",
            "longitude": "9.1552",
            "post code": "70597",
            "latitude": "48.7446"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Schönberg",
            "longitude": "9.2001",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.7325"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Steckfeld",
            "longitude": "9.2014",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.7153"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Birkach",
            "longitude": "9.2108",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.7082"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Plieningen",
            "longitude": "9.2107",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.701"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Asemwald",
            "longitude": "9.1932",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.726"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Hohenheim",
            "longitude": "9.2113",
            "post code": "70599",
            "latitude": "48.7118"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Heumaden",
            "longitude": "9.2376",
            "post code": "70619",
            "latitude": "48.7463"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70619",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Lederberg",
            "longitude": "9.243",
            "post code": "70619",
            "latitude": "48.7532"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Sillenbuch",
            "longitude": "9.2074",
            "post code": "70619",
            "latitude": "48.7474"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Riedenberg",
            "longitude": "9.2134",
            "post code": "70619",
            "latitude": "48.736"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart Flughafen",
            "longitude": "9.2121",
            "post code": "70629",
            "latitude": "48.6836"
        },
        {
            "place name": "Stuttgart",
            "longitude": "9.1833",
            "post code": "70629",
            "latitude": "48.7667"
        }
    ],
    "country": "Germany",
    "place name": "Stuttgart Stuttgart-Mitte",
    "state": "Baden-Württemberg",
    "state abbreviation": "BW"
}

So far I have done until this Step and have hard coded places as 105. I would like to now extend it, try and find out dynamically by reading the whole JSON file and using a proper logic, whereby requesting your help in that regard. I have seen the other posts on similar topics, but they are not exactly what I am after unfortunately.
pm.test("Places", function () {
    const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.places[105]['post code']).to.eql("70597");
    console.log(responseJson.places[105]['place name']);
});


Postman uses JavaScript under the hood.
The value for your places key in the response is an array.
Therefore, this can be acheived using the JavaScript find function.
const response = pm.response.json();

let placeToFind = "Stuttgart Degerloch";

let search = (response.places.find(obj => {return obj["place name"] === placeToFind}));
console.log(search);


pm.test("Response includes Stuttgart Degerloch", function () {
    pm.expect(search).to.not.be.undefined
    pm.expect(search['post code']).to.eql("70567");
});


Noticed you had the wrong post code in your example code.  70597 instead of 70567.

Once corrected in the code...


Thank you so much for the Response. Actually there is an Object with Post Code "70597" and "place name": "Stuttgart Degerloch" in the JSON I shared, so this is not a Typo :) and thats what I am actually after.
I ran your Code as is and it works. But when I changed the Post Code from 70567 to 70597" in the following Step, I got the Error( AssertionError: expected '70567' to deeply equal '70597')
pm.expect(search['post code']).to.eql("70597");
Could you please help me again in finding the Object with Post Code "70597"? Many thanks in advance

Hello @mikee,
So I tried and change your provided logic a little bit and seem to got it working :). Let me know your thoughts, please?
const response = pm.response.json();
let placeToFind = "Stuttgart Degerloch";
let postCode = "70597";
let search = (response.places.find(obj => {return obj["post code"] === postCode}));
console.log(search);
pm.test("Response includes Stuttgart Degerloch - Stackoverflow", function () {
pm.expect(search).to.not.be.undefined
//    pm.expect(search['post code']).to.eql("70597");
pm.expect(search['place name']).to.eql(placeToFind);
});

Whether you search on the Post code or Place name is entirely down to you and which of those two things are the most important.    However, which ever key you use for the search doesn't also need to have an assertion.  If the find returns an object and the variable is not undefined, then that should give you the assurances that the key is found.  The assertion for the other element in the object should then provide extra assurances that the correct object has been returned.  The test is that the place name and post code match.  Whether that is the correct test is down to you to decide.

One other thing to consider is whether the post code is unique in that response. Are there post codes with multiple places. Ideally, you need to search on a key that is unique. If there is the chance of multiple objects with the same post code, then you need to us "filter" instead of "find" and then check how many objects are returned.  Or you can change the "find" to search for the name and postcode, which hopefully should be unique and you can then just test to ensure the search is not undefined.

Many thanks again for the Details. Could you please provide me with the Code Snippet for Filtering as well, if thats OK?

It's exactly the same, you just swap the word "find" for "filter".
